# Trying to create a Forum in MVC 5 / ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, frameworks

I'm trying to create a basic forum in ASP.NET MVC 5 and I am really stuck at a "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint" error.
I will post my class and controller for this assignment and an image that illustrates how I want this to work.

Thread.cs

```
namespace BlogProject.Models
{
    public class Thread
    {
        [Key]
        public int ThreadId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PostDate { get; set; }
        public string ThreadText { get; set; }
        public string ThreadTitle { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser UserProfile { get; set; }
        public string GetUserName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }
        public string PostText { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PostDate { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser UserProfile { get; set; }

        public virtual Thread Thread { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Thread")]
        public int ThreadId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

PostsController.cs

```
// POST: Posts/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PostId,PostTitle,PostText,PostDate,ThreadId")] Post post,Thread thread)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Posts.Add(post);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Threads");
    }

    ViewBag.ThreadId = new SelectList(db.Threads, "ThreadId", "ThreadText", post.ThreadId);
    return View("Details");
}
```

This is how I want it to work:

[Forum goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuQ1e.png)
If you think the information here is not sufficient then tell me and I will add more.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE EDIT:

Sorry, forgot to include my Views

Details.cshtml, this is where my Threads go

```
@model BlogProject.Models.Thread

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div class="container">
    <h3>Current thread: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ThreadTitle), Posted by: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.GetUserName)</h3>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img class="img-responsive user-photo" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="well-lg">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ThreadText)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="text-center">
        @Html.ActionLink("Reply to this thread","Create","Posts")
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
</div>
```

Posts/Create.cshtml (Partial view)

```
@model BlogProject.Models.Post

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Post</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I will post more Views if needed. Sorry for taking so long to answer, I'm mostly lying down on the couch sleeping today.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the data you're trying to save doesn't satisfy a foreign key constraint in the database.  What foreign keys do you have in that table?  What values are you inserting?  Do the values for the foreign keys have corresponding values in the related tables?  According to the error, they don't.

Comment: show your view page, its important

Answer (score 0):

First change the `Post`model because your not assigning `Primary Key` and `foreign Key`

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    .
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ThreadId")]
    public virtual Thread Thread { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Thread thread)
```

Because in the view page you have used only

```
@model BlogProject.Models.Thread
```

The `post` object will be null and try 'thread'

```
db.Posts.Add(post);
```

hope this helps

Comment: What does the dot stand for under PostId? Should I remove all my code between that and ThreadId?

Comment: you silly. i written answer shortly. the correction are in the three lines. you have place all lines.

Comment: [Post Exception error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vuovs.png)     It gives me an exception when I try to submit a reply to the thread

Comment: No :( I've been too sick to even sit in front of my computer. And I don't understand much at this point haha